# No errors, but code crashes after 2nd input

Tags: c++, variables, printf

I need to write this program that calculates a movie theater's profits for school. It was first written using <>cin, but then I needed to rewrite it using printf. There are zero errors with the code, it just crashes after you input the number of adult ticket sales.

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ char movie[50];

printf("What is the name of the movie?");
scanf(" %s", movie);

int AdultSales, ChildrenSales;

printf("How many adults attended? ");
scanf(" %d", AdultSales);

printf("How many children attended? ");
scanf(" %d", ChildrenSales);

float GrossBoxOfficeProfit= ChildrenSales*9.25+AdultSales*11.25;
float AmountPaidToDistributer=GrossBoxOfficeProfit*0.8;
float NetBoxOfficeProfit=GrossBoxOfficeProfit-AmountPaidToDistributer;

scanf("movie: %s",movie);
scanf("\nAdult tickets sold: %d",AdultSales);
scanf("\nChild tickest sold: %d",ChildrenSales);
scanf("\nGross Box office profit: $%f",GrossBoxOfficeProfit);
scanf("\nNet Box office proft: $%f",NetBoxOfficeProfit);
scanf("\nAmount paid to distributer: $%f",AmountPaidToDistributer);

return  0;
```

}`

Comment: Hi @Jtack51, welcome to SO! you need to pass the address of an integer as argument to the scanf `scanf(" %d", &AdultSales);`. similarly for `ChildrenSales`

Answer (score 0):

Scanf takes a pointer to the integer instead of integer itself, try to change it:

```
int AdultSales, ChildrenSales;

printf("How many adults attended? ");
scanf(" %d", &AdultSales);

printf("How many children attended? ");
scanf(" %d", &ChildrenSales);
```

You can see the function reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do this there was mistake which are corrected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ char movie[50];

printf("What is the name of the movie?");
scanf(" %s", movie);

int AdultSales, ChildrenSales;

printf("How many adults attended? ");
scanf(" %d", &AdultSales); //scanf(" %d", AdultSales);

printf("How many children attended? ");
scanf(" %d", &ChildrenSales); //scanf(" %d", ChildrenSales);

float GrossBoxOfficeProfit= ChildrenSales*9.25+AdultSales*11.25;
float AmountPaidToDistributer=GrossBoxOfficeProfit*0.8;
float NetBoxOfficeProfit=GrossBoxOfficeProfit-AmountPaidToDistributer;


printf("movie: %s",movie);
printf("\nAdult tickets sold: %d",AdultSales);
printf("\nChild ticket sold: %d",ChildrenSales);
printf("\nGross Box office profit: %f",GrossBoxOfficeProfit);
printf("\nNet Box office profit: %f",NetBoxOfficeProfit);
printf("\nAmount paid to distributer: %f",AmountPaidToDistributer);

return  0;
}
```

this part is wrong

```
    //scanf("movie: %s",movie);
    //scanf("\nAdult tickets sold: %d",AdultSales);
    //scanf("\nChild tickest sold: %d",ChildrenSales);
    //scanf("\nGross Box office profit: $%f",GrossBoxOfficeProfit);
    //scanf("\nNet Box office proft: $%f",NetBoxOfficeProfit);
    //scanf("\nAmount paid to distributer: $%f",AmountPaidToDistributer);
```